# Simple flow not updating record

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a very simple flow that is triggered by a process. Everything seems to work fine, except for the record update. I cannot figure out the problem, and have made many changes based on internet advise.

Flow logic:
once the flow is triggered, by updating StageName in an Opp, i loop thru all opps related to a the account ID passed in by the process (account Id related to the opp that was updated).

For each Opp, if the Stage is not equal to 'X. Closed / Lost', I set a Boolean to ''True (default value of bool is 'False').

Once the loop ends, i check the value of the Boolean.

If false, i update the 'account status' field of the account with ID matching the one that was passed in by the process.

There are no errors, and the log appears to be showing that the update happened. any Idea?

Here's the log:

> 16:06:24.56 (166680841)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1 16:06:24.56
>   (166704078)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Set
>   Account Status to Dead/Lost 16:06:24.56
>   (166742593)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|vOppAccountId|001q000000mVfJvAAK
>   16:06:24.56
>   (166820403)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct
>   16:06:24.56
>   (166833996)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct
>   16:06:24.56
>   (166841067)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct
>   16:06:24.56
>   (166850133)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Set
>   Account Status to Dead/Lost 16:06:24.56
>   (166877994)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247209638)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|vRelatedOpps|[{Id=006q000000EkIz5AAF,
>   StageName=X. Closed Lost}] 16:06:24.56
>   (247238991)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct|true
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247264694)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct|1
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247324923)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowRecordLookup|Find_all_Opps_related_to_acct|1|81
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247356369)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowLoop|Loop_thru_Opps
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247477076)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Loop_thru_Opps.currentIteration|0
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247490955)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|vCurrentOpp|{Id=006q000000EkIz5AAF,
>   StageName=X. Closed Lost} 16:06:24.56
>   (247628434)|FLOW_LOOP_DETAIL|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|0|006q000000EkIz5AAF
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247645934)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowLoop|Loop_thru_Opps
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247661147)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowDecision|is_this_an_open_or_won_opp
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247886582)|FLOW_RULE_DETAIL|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Yes|false
>   16:06:24.56
>   (247896527)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|Yes|false 16:06:24.56
>   (247904656)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|742cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-6189|FlowDecision|is_this_an_open_or_won_opp
>   16:06:24.56 (247928287)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1 16:06:24.56
>   (248303505)|FLOW_ACTIONCALL_DETAIL|741cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-618a|myRule_1_A1|Flows|Set_Account_Status_to_Dead_Lost|true|
>   16:06:24.56
>   (248318470)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|741cb60b2b87f8dbf6a227c6b8161f7e9ee76-618a|myRule_1_A1|true
>   16:06:24.56
>   (248331155)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowActionCall|myRule_1_A1|0|181
>   16:06:24.56 (248358945)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1 16:06:24.28
>   (249271729)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09L4A000000GtOc 16:06:24.28
>   (249392011)|WF_ACTIONS_END| Field Update: 1; Flow Trigger: 1;
>   16:06:24.28 (249399431)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Opportunity
>   16:06:24.28 (250386144)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Comment: I find flows extremely inefficient, I have had to convert too many flows to trigger code because of SOQL violations that it's just not worth using them anymore. I recommend using a trigger.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Is the Opp ID not populating on the account correctly? What happens if the boolean is set to true? The log makes it look like the boolean was set to true, but it might not do anything at that point.

Comment: It looks like the update is being triggered, but not performing the action because it doesn't find accounts that meet the filter criteria. when the process is triggered, it passes the account ID to the flow in a variable. the update action uses that variable to match the correct account to update. maybe the variable is empty at that point for some reason and the account is not found. I have opened a support case 2 days ago, but am still waiting for an answer.